# geopandas AttributeError: 'MultiPolygon' object has no attribute 'exterior'

Tags: python, pandas, polygon, shapely, geopandas

I have two  GeoDataFrame. One is of the state of Iowa, while the other is of foretasted rain over the next 72 hours for North America.  I want to create a GeoDataFrame of the rain forecast where it overlies the state of Iowa. But I get an error.

```
state_rain = gpd.overlay(NA_rain,iowa,how='intersection')      

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-39-ba8264ed63c2> in <module>()
  3 #ws_usa[['WTRSHD_ID','QPF']].groupby('WTRSHD_ID').max().reset_index()
  4 #state_rain = sjoin(usa_r,usa,how='inner',op='intersects')
----> 5 state_rain = gpd.overlay(usa_r,joined_states,how='intersection')
  6 ws_state = gpd.overlay(ws,joined_states,how='intersection')
  7 #print ws_usa.loc[ws_usa.WTRSHD_ID == 'IA-04']['QPF']

C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\geopandas\tools\overlay.pyc in overlay(df1, df2, how, use_sindex)
 95 
 96     # Collect the interior and exterior rings
---> 97     rings1 = _extract_rings(df1)
 98     rings2 = _extract_rings(df2)
 99     mls1 = MultiLineString(rings1)

C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\geopandas\tools\overlay.pyc in     _extract_rings(df)
 50                 # geom from layer is not valid attempting fix by buffer 0"
 51                 geom = geom.buffer(0)
---> 52             rings.append(geom.exterior)
 53             rings.extend(geom.interiors)
 54 

AttributeError: 'MultiPolygon' object has no attribute 'exterior'
```

I checked for type == 'MultiPolygon', but neither GeoDataFrame contain any.

```
print NA_rain[NA_rain.geometry.type == 'MulitPolygon']
print iowa[iowa.geometry.type == 'MultiPolygon']

Empty GeoDataFrame
Columns: [END_TIME, ID, ISSUE_TIME, PRODUCT, QPF, START_TIME, UNITS, VALID_TIME, geometry]
Index: []
Empty GeoDataFrame
Columns: [sid, AFFGEOID, ALAND, AWATER, GEOID, LSAD, NAME, STATEFP, STATENS, STUSPS, geometry]
Index: []
```

If I do the following, the intersection works.

```
NA_rain.geometry = NA_rain.geometry.map(lambda x: x.convex_hull)
```

My question is twofold: 1.Why don't any MultiPolygons show up in my NA_rain GeoDataFrame, and 2. Besides turning every Polygon into a convex_hull, which ruins detailed contours of the Polygon, how would you suggest dealing with the MultiPolygon issue.

Comment: debug it by printing the geometry before and after `geom.buffer(0)`

Comment: To the first question: in your snippet here, at least, your equality check is `NA_rain.geometry.type == 'MulitPolygon'`, rather than `NA_rain.geometry.type == 'MultiPolygon'`. Is that just a transcription error, or is there any chance that `NA_rain` does have `MultiPolygon` entries?

Comment: @O.D.P Can you replicate the problem with a small subset of the data (that you could maybe share here?). It's difficult to know what could be wrong without having access to the data

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @jdmcbr. I suspect that at least one of the features in `NA_rain` is a MultiPolygon which did not get detected since the condition you showed is misspelled (`MulitPolygon` instead of `MultiPolygon`).

If your dataframe has MultiPolygons, you can convert all of them to Polygons. One dirty was is by passing the `list()` function to each MultiPolygon and then exploding into multiple rows:

```
geom = NA_rain.pop('geometry')
geom = geom.apply(lambda x: list(x) if isinstance(x, MultiPolygon) else x).explode())
NA_rain = NA_rain.join(geom, how='inner')
```

Note that the joining in line 3 duplicates the other attributes of the dataframe for all Polygons of the MultiPolygon, including feature identifiers, which you may want to change later, depending on your task.